# svn: how to copy changes from one feature branch to another

Tags: svn

I'm currently working on two svn branches, one called A and one called B.  Branch A is mostly done and almost ready to merge into the base branch. Branch B is new, and I want to pull in some work from branch A to B since I added some useful infrastructure. I tried a simple merge of A into B, which seemed to work (`svn merge ^/branches/A .`).  However, at a later stage, when A was merged back into the base branch, I tried merging the base branch into B and got a ton of tree conflicts because the files are being added again. **How should I have done the prior merge to avoid this problem?**

```
 . A created    . A merged (all is well)
-------------------------------> Base Branch
 |          |   |                               
 -----------|---- Branch A   
            |                
            -------------------> Branch B
            ^  ^             ^
  B created |  |             | merged base into B, explosions occur
               |
               | merged A into B (svn merge ^/branches/A .)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `svn merge --record-only` the revision which is a result of merge of A into base, it is the one confusing the `svn`. Then try the original merge again. Instead of doing A->base it is better to do it like base->a->base, in which case merge conflicts are resolved on A, not on base and you could have merged that result up to B too without problems.

Comment: It wasn't merge conflicts so much as tree conflicts (there were no conflicts merging base into A or A base back into base) caused by svn trying to add files twice.  The real-life situation may have slightly more complex.  However, using `svn log` I was able to track down the original merge revision, and with `svn merge --record-only branch@rev .` I was able to tell svn not to repeat all of its changes again.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around the purpose of --record-only and SVN's design. It almost feels like a weird nuisance bandaid task to make up for some design flaw. Our source is so cluttered with these record only merges that it obscures the real meat of changes.